# How to create a dynamic object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Javacript (with jQuery) to create a Manager object to my user interfaces. The general idea is capturing all clickable elements (defined with .clickable class) and then, based on the id of the element, create the corresponding object to deal with the action needed.

This is my Manager object definition:

```
function Manager() {

    this.init = function() {
        $('.clickable').click( function() {
            var l = this.id.split("_");
            var controller = Manager.ucfirst(l[0]) + "()";
            var action = l[1];
            var nclass = new controler;
        });
    };

    this.init();
}
```

When the user clicks a clickable element like

```
<a id="user_login" class="clickable">Login</a>
```

then this Manager should create an object User (the first part of the id with an uppercase first letter) and then execute method login (second part of the id).

But what happens, in fact, is that when I click the element I receive a "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function".

Well, I know that string is not a function! But I am assuming Javascript is smart enoough to have something like the $$variable in PHP.

I've done some research but with no practical results. Would someone help me, please?

Comment: Is `User` defined globally?

Comment: Yes, it is. But this is surely not the problem, because it does not complain about User definition, but even before this it complains about this 'string is not a function' thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you may go about that:

```
function Manager() {

    this.init = function() {

        $('.clickable').click( function() {
            var l = this.id.split("_");

            var controller = Manager[l[0][0].toUpperCase() + l[0].substring(1)];
            var action = l[1];

            var nclass = new controler;
        });

    };

    this.init();
 }
```

The point is that you should assign a function type to the controller, not a string that looks like a function invocation expression. That should work if the referred instance of Manager has a property defined which is named as the evaluation of `Manager[l[0][0].toUpperCase() + l[0].substring(1)]`. Otherwise, it will yet fail.

I must say the context of your issue is not very clear to me, so I suggest the following approach which might solve your problem better and wholly:

```
var Manager = ({
    User: function(){ // here's your user constructor
          // ...
    },
    init: function() {

        var self = this;

        $('.clickable').click( function() {
            var l = this.id.split("_");

            var controller, nclass,
                action = l[1],
                controllerName = l[0][0].toUpperCase() + l[0].substring(1);

            if(self[controllerName]){ // checking if it exist cos you never know where the shit that happens all come from.
                controller = self[controllerName]; // returns the constructor
                nclass = new controler; // invokes the constructor
            } else{
                throw new Error("Don't know what to do with unknown controller: '" + controllerName + "'";
            }

        });

        return this; // i.e self
    }
}).init();
```

Comment: What is the meaning of l[0][0]? I'm asking because split is going to return a one-dimension array, not a two-dimensions array.

Comment: hi @ederpsampaio, if `l[0]` evaluated to the **string** `"user"` for instance, then `l[0][0]` would evaluate to the string `"u"`.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks. But what happens if I can't define User inside Manager? In fact, I need to define it in another javascript file also loaded in the same document. This way I may add new objects without hardcoding them inside Manager. Is it possible to do the same like this?

Comment: Having read your other comments, you are able to see that `User` is defined in the context of the `window` object. In that you may access the constructor function as follows: `var controller = window[l[0][0].toUpperCase() + l[0].substring(1)];`. And that should be it..

Comment: meanwhile, @ederpsampaio consider marking my answer as **the answer** if it has helped you resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code `Manager.ucfirst(l[0]) + "()"` it will return you a string like "User()". Obviously this is not a constructor function to be used with `new` keyword. What you should do instead is something like this (providing that `User` is available globally):

```
var controller = window[Manager.ucfirst(l[0])];
```

Here you grab `window` object property by key. So `controller` in this case is going to be a `function` and everything should work.

Comment: Well, the error changed a bit now... Now it says "undefined is not a function". User is globally defined, by the way. :(

Comment: what is `Manager.ucfirst(l[0])` ?

Comment: ucfirst ia a method defined in Manager. It receives a string and returns ir with the first letter in uppercase.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking what is the result of this code `Manager.ucfirst(l[0])`?

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry. Well, if one clicks the <a id="user_login" class="clickable">Login</a>, as I said in the question, the result of this code will surely be "User".

Comment: If you are sure that the result of this code is string `User`, then `User` constructor **is not** defined globally.

Comment: How and where do define `User`?

Comment: I define user in another Javascript file, also included in the same document. And I checked with console.log(window). The User function is indeed defined there, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Try this in console: `window["User"]`. What does it return?

Comment: It returned function User() { }, the definition I had written to User object. As you see, it is ok this side. the question is: why it does not return it in a functional way, so I can use "new window["User"]":

Comment: Yes you should be fine now. `new window["User"]` is correct. The problem is probably somewhere inside.

Comment: Agreed, @dfsq. Don't really know what can it be. If you have any other idea, I'll be glad to listen. Thanks for you help, my friend.

Comment: Well you should put `debugger` key word and debug it step by step. And see where program has a problem. Or if you can replicate the error in jsfiddle it would help.

Comment: How and where `User` is defined is not the problem. The root of the issue lies in the following expression: `Manager.ucfirst(l[0]) + "()"`. First `ucfirst` is defined as a property of the `Manager` Function, and neither is it a native JavaScript function. `ucfirst` should be undefined then, unless you added it somewhere. - That's the root cause. But even if was defined, you don't get the constructor by appending a string `"()"` to it.

Comment: Speaking about debugging, you'd be better of putting a break point at the beginning of where it matters and watching the expressions while you step through your codes.